# Second Order Cone Program with Quadratic Objective

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, convex-cone, second-order-cone-programming

The standard form for a Second Order Cone Program (SOCP)

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\min _{x} f^{T} x \\
\left\|A_{i} x+b_{i}\right\|_{2} \leq c_{i}^{T} x+d_{i}, i=1, \ldots, m
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $ A_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{k_{i} \times n}, b_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{k_{i}}, c_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \text { and } d_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$.

If the objective is quadratic instead we have

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\min _{x} x^{T}\Sigma x \\
\left\|A_{i} x+b_{i}\right\|_{2} \leq c_{i}^{T} x+d_{i}, i=1, \ldots, m
\end{array}
\end{equation}

is there a classification for this type of problem? It looks like it is still a convex problem since both constraints and objective are convex.

Also, is there any way to proceed to solve this type of problem through KKT or any designed numerical solver to handle this problems?

Comment: It is convex if and only if $\Sigma$ is positive semidefinite and in this case you can also represent it as a second order conic constraint in a standard way, for example: https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#quadratically-constrained-quadratic-optimization

Comment: What about the solution? Do you have any hint? Is there a closed form solution? Is there any solver available?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a closed form solution in general. Any SOCP solver (if the objective is convex).

Comment: SOCP solver usually solve a linear objective, am I wrong?

Comment: Minimize $f(x)$ is the same as minimize $y$ subject to $y\geq f(x)$. You can move all nonlinearities to constraints.